# Summation of a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Could anyone help me solve this term?

$$\sum_{x=n}^{N}\binom{x}{n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What does ${x_C}_n$ mean?  What have you done so far?

Comment: I assume $~^xC_n$ is the notation you were trying for.  I recommend using instead the notation $\binom{x}{n}$ for a binomial coefficient as it is far more common.

Comment: Is $x_{C_n}$ $\binom xn$?

Comment: yes the binomial coefficient